# Raycast reporting a collision in the wrong place

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript, raycasting

I'm having a strange problem with my raycasts.

I've a soldier character with some capsule colliders on various body parts to have body-part specific damage and they have a specific layer to only hit them. The character also has a character controller on the root. I currently use raycasts to grab whatever information I need on what the raycast hit.

For some reason, the raycasts are reporting a collision on a completely different position from the collider it supposedly hits. It would say it's hitting the LlegUpperCollider but the hit point is somewhere a bit above the character. The editor shows that the collider is where its supposed to be. They seem to translate and orient themselves correctly with the character animation as well.

Here's a screenshot: [image].

I've circled the hit point and I've drawn an arrow to where the collider actually is.

You'll see two lines. The red one, that shows the raycast direction and hit point, has its origin on the enemies weapon position and it finishes on `hit.point`. The blue one The red one has its origin on the enemies weapon position and it finishes on `hit.collider.transform.position`

The script is on the soldier gun and uses the soldier object to place the rays. Here is the code:

```
enemyTransform = enemyObject.transform;  // enemyObject is a GameObject (the soldier object)
var ray : Ray;
ray.origin = enemyTransform.position + enemyTransform.up * 1.5 + enemyTransform.right * 0.25;
ray.direction = enemyTransform.forward;

var hit : RaycastHit;

if(Physics.Raycast(ray.origin + ray.direction * 0.1, ray.direction, hit, fireRange, hitLayer.value))
{   

   if (hit.collider.tag == GameManager.tagColliderHead || hit.collider.tag == GameManager.tagColliderChest ||   hit.collider.tag == GameManager.tagColliderExtremities) 
   {
      Debug.Log("CR -COLLIDER = "+hit.collider.tag+" name = "+hit.collider.name+"Hit.point = "+hit.point);

      Utils.DibujarLinea(line1, ray.origin, hit.point, Color.red, Color.red);
      Utils.DibujarLinea(line2, ray.origin, hit.collider.transform.position, Color.blue, Color.blue);

   }
}
```

Utils.DibujarLinea() is:

```
static function DibujarLinea(linea : LineRenderer, StartPoint : Vector3, EndPoint : Vector3, Color1 : Color, Color2 : Color)
   {
      linea.SetColors(Color1, Color2);
      linea.useWorldSpace = true;
      linea.SetWidth(0.02f,0.02f);
      linea.SetVertexCount(2);
      linea.SetPosition(0, StartPoint);
      linea.SetPosition(1, EndPoint);
   }
```

Comment: How did you draw the two lines? It doesn't look like they have the same origin.

Comment: In fact, they have the same origin. The problem is that de hit.point is wrong. The collider hitten position is "touched" by the blue line. But the hit point that sould be in the collider is in other place.. Both lines are generated in the gun position wich is holded by another soldier. That soldier isn´t shown in the picture and is far away from the soldier on the pic.

The blue one starts on ray.origin and ends on hit.collider.transform.position and the other one starts on ray.origin and ends on hit.point. I used LineRenderer

Comment: Please add the code that draws your lines to the question. The blue line is coming from the left side and the red one from approx. behind.  There is now way that they have the same origin. Maybe it's easier to use `Debug.DrawLine()` for that matter.

Comment: Its just a view effect..

Comment: Code looks fine as long as there is no other code that could override line renderer `line1`. Check that the collider has the correct size and orientation. `hit.point` will return the exact coordinates where the ray hit the collider, while `hit.transform.position` will return the position of the collider. There is nothing wrong if they not return the same coordinates. Maybe add another screenshot with a more top-down perspective, that shows better where the rays end in relation to the soldier.